# Select object with diff in where

Tags: mysql

I trying to find a way to run this:

```
SELECT 
    s.system_number,
    s.total_points,
    p.licensed_points,
    SUM(p.licensed_points) - SUM(s.total_points) AS difference_points
FROM 
    server AS s 
    LEFT JOIN 
        practice AS p ON p.system_number = s.system_number 
WHERE 
    difference_points < 0
```

My goal is to select object only where difference_points < 0

Someone know how to do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using aggregation function `Sum()` without `Group By` does not make sense here. You will need to do a `Group By` on `s.system_number`.
- Then, you can use `Having` clause to consider the cases where `difference_points` is less than 0.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
    s.system_number,
    SUM(s.total_points),
    SUM(p.licensed_points),
    SUM(p.licensed_points) - SUM(s.total_points) AS difference_points
FROM 
    server AS s 
    LEFT JOIN 
        practice AS p ON p.system_number = s.system_number 
GROUP BY 
  s.system_number 
HAVING 
    difference_points < 0
```